# i have problem installing truffle ,when i try npm truffle -v i get this error message

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, blockchain, nodejs

```sh
truffle : File C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
+ truffle init
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a PowerShell issue that only runs signed scripts by default for security reasons.

You can run the following command in your session to disable this check, it is valid only for the current powershell process :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

On a side note, it might be that your User / Process execution policy is set to : `AllSigned` which you can check with :

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

If that is the case, you can change to the `RemoteSigned` policy which should allow you to run truffle ps1 :

> The AllSigned policy allows us to run only scripts that have been
> digitally signed by a trusted publisher. The RemoteSigned policy
> allows us to run scripts that we have created locally, but scripts
> that we download must be digitally signed by a trusted publisher.

With the following command for the current process only :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

Or this one for a system-wide change (Powershell needs administrator rights) :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

If you wish to disable it permanently (not recommended), you can use an administrator powershell and use :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```